# Ознакамливать

Tags: грамотная-речь

есть ли слово ознакамливать? Администрация    (что делает?)......?   Человек (что делает?) с материалами дала?

Answer (score 3):

Форма *ознакамливать/ся* является морфологическим вариантом глагола несов. вида *ознакомлять/ся* : в ней применен другой суффикс и корневое чередование о/а (типа *обработать/обрабатывать*, обустроить/обустраивать...)

> 1.1.3. Вариативность -о-/-а- в корне глаголов НСВ
> При образовании имперфективов от некоторых глаголов СВ с ударным (хотя бы в части форм) -о- в корне возможна замена этого -о- на -а- (закончить – заканчивать, установить, установит – устанавливать).

Редкость применения этого глагола (*ознакамливать*) не говорит о его "неправильности". В [ссылке](http://rusgram.ru/Несовершенный_вид) осторожно говорится о выходе слова из активного употребления в литературе :

> Сюда же, возможно, относятся глаголы ознакамливать / ознакомливать (11/9, только 1 пример после 1953 г.)

Примеры из Нацкорпуса :

> Д. В. Григорович. Переселенцы (1855-1856) ― смеясь, сказал старик, делавшийся веселее по мере того, как **ознакамливался** с хозяевами.
> Сборник боевых документов ВОВ. (1941-1945)
> В случае необходимости изготовления документа с содержанием последнего **ознакамливать** только ограниченный круг лиц под расписку, не распространяя документов за пределы штаба, изготовляющего эти документы.
> А. И. Солженицын. Архипелаг ГУЛаг (1958-1973)
> Встречаясь же, **ознакамливались** с точкой зрения друг друга!
>
> В. В. Крестовский. Петербургские трущобы. Книга о сытых и голодных. (1867)
> Такой грех обыкновенно случался с неофитами, которые на первый раз не вполне еще **ознакамливались** с обычаями и уставами птичьего гнезда.
> В. Н. Гельфанд. Дневники 1944-1946 гг.
> ― Пока вам нечего делать ― транспорта нет. Вы **ознакамливайтесь**. И особенно я вас попрошу помочь выпустить стенгазету и оформить плакаты к Октябрьским дням...

Глагол *ознакамливать/ся* до сих пор в ходу, по крайней мере - в повседневной речи. Это правильная, но относительно редкая форма НВ от глагола СВ *ознакомить/ся*. Примеры (их миллион) морфологических вариантов глаголов НВ : восстанавливать/ся - восстановлять/ся, придуриваться - придуряться, накоплять - накапливать. РГ-80 :

> §1402. В суффиксальной видовой паре при одной основе могут создаваться **вариативные образования глаголов** несов. вида с морфами -ива- или -а3-. Так, например, при глаголе сов. вида уловить есть глаголы несов. вида уловлять и улавливать; при затопить (залить водой), (погрузить в воду) - затоплять и затапливать; при одарить - одарять (высок.) и одаривать; при установить - устанавливать и установлять (устар. и прост.); при разрезать - разрезывать (редко) и разрезать; при накопить - накоплять (прост.) и накапливать; при заготовить - заготовлять и заготавливать. Иногда эти вариативные образования **различаются стилистически**; например: одарять (высок.) и одаривать; накоплять (прост.) и накапливать.

Посмотрел частотность в гугл-поиске :
*ознакомляться* ~ 88 900
*ознакамливаться* ~ 56 400 ...
Наш сабж совсем не желает выходить из употребления в повседневном человеческом общении, материалах масс-медиа и сетевых текстах. Действительно, две формы глагола НВ имеют разную стилистическую окраску. 
Читать - но читывать и почитывать (оттенок неопределенности, необязательности, прерывности действия в двух последних примерах). "Да знаем, читывали!"
Ознакомляться с материалами - плотно изучать, читать документы и тд. Ознакамливаться с делами - по диагонали пробежаться по страницам, на ходу просмотреть почту, не особо вникая в суть проблем. Есть, есть отличия и нюансы, на то и суффиксы разные.

Answer (score 2):

В словарях указываются следующие видовые пары: ознакомить - ознакомлять, ознакомиться - ознакомляться.

В словаре Резниченко (2009 год) вариант "ознакамливать /ознакамливаться" имеет пометку "неправильно!".